# Authentication failure with Slim Basic Auth

Tags: php, api, slim, http-authentication

So I'm working with tuupola/slim-basic-auth, with Slim. I think I followed the steps correctly and yet something is not working properly.

So here is my index.php

```
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
"users" => [
    "user" => "Carla",
    "password" => "123"
],
"realm" => "Protected",
"secure" => false,
"path" => '/',
"error" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
    $data = [];
    $data["status"] = "error";
    $data["message"] = $arguments["message"];
    return $response->write(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
}
]));
```

I'm testing it with Postman, I fill the authentication with my credentials, and I get a 401 Unauthorised.
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I finally saw what was wrong. Turns out it was missing this line:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

on the `.htaccess` file.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If username you want is `Carla` and password `123` then init the middleware like this:

```
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
    "users" => [
        "Carla" => "123"
    ]
]));
```

Comment: In the meantime I figured that out, but the error is just the same, 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Check what your Postman is actually sending. Use for example Curl instead.

Comment: I'm kinda new to this, so how do I use curl exactly?

Comment: I think I managed using curl
here's what I wrote in the terminal: curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"carla:123"}' http://sandoz-api.dev/public/
And the message was just the same: Authentication Failed

Answer (score 1):

in the

> .htaccess

```
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```